# Can i add an exchange calendar to sharepoint?

Tags: calendar, exchange

Is the question in the title possible? Are there any known (serious) issues?

Comment: on prem or sharepoint online?

Answer (score 2):

You can add Exchange Calendar as an Overlay.

1. Open Calendar Ribbon
2. Then select Over Lay
3. Add calendar
4. Select Exchange
5. Provide Exchange OWA URL
6. Pick the Calendar